# Why do I need to have site unique form element id's when using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, dom

Why do I need to have site unique form element id's when using jQuery Mobile? I would really like to know how the DOM works in order to create my app memory efficient.

I get this information about the DOM cache:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/pages/

> Whenever it loads a page via AJAX, it flags the page to be removed
>   from the DOM when you navigate away from it later (technically, on the
>   pagehide event).

So this information about Markup conventions seems to be contradicting, or at least incomplete:
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/forms/

> ...the id attributes of form
>   controls need to be not only unique on a given page, but also unique
>   across the pages in a site.
>   This is because jQuery Mobile's single-page navigation model allows
>   many different "pages" to be present in the DOM at the same time. You
>   must be careful to use unique id attributes so there will be only one
>   of each in the DOM.

Comment: because if you add `data-dom-cache="true"` attribute to a page, it won't be removed. The default value of that attribute is `false`, but its used in cased you want to keep external pages loaded in DOM. http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/page/#option-domCache

Comment: The long and short of it is you will run into conflicts in your DOM. Omar is right on the money there.